# rails how add a response when raising a custom exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, backend, response

When raising an exception in rails, I would like to add a custom response as well.
For example if Im making a custom 404 exception, then i would like the response to be something like `msg: "no record found`. I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
raise customError, "msg: no record found"
```

but that doesnt seem to work. Is there another way I can go about this?

Comment: what do you mean by does not work? Are you getting an error?

Comment: doesnt work as in I see nothing in the response from the browser

Comment: you need to share more information for us. for example the code you render the response and your `customError` class code.

Comment: I suggest reading about [`rescue_from` in the official Rails Guides](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html#method-i-rescue_from).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `rescue_from` to rescue all your customErrors in your controller, and then render the response

```
class ApplicationController 
  rescue_from CustomError do |exception|
    render_json json: { msg: exception.message }, status: 404
  end
end
```